# Can System.Windows.Forms be added to a WinRT project?

Tags: c#, winforms, reference, windows-8, windows-runtime

I want to add a class library the uses he System.Windows.Forms namespace to my Windows 8 app. When I add the namespace and build the solution, I get one error:

```
 Cannot find type System.Resources.ResourceSet in module mscorlib.dll.
```

Is it possible to add System.Windows.Forms?

Comment: As I said, there is a class library that is reliant on System.Windows.Forms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `System.Windows.Forms` is not supported in Windows Store apps. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232.aspx) is the list of all supported .NET namespaces and classes in them.

You can't just reference existing .NET assemblies from Windows Store apps. They need to be either portable class libraries or class libraries for Windows Store apps.